# widgetcolumn: bind visibility of widget to dataIndex

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a widgetcolumn that contains a button:

```
xtype:'widgetcolumn',
dataIndex: 'canUpdateKey',
itemId:'updateKey',
width:120,
widget: {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Update key',
    hidden: '{!record.canUpdateKey}'
}
```

I only want to display the button where `canUpdateKey` is true on the record; but this does not work as indented. [Relevant fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [widget](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Widget.html#cfg-widget) config documentation:

> The rendered component has a Ext.app.ViewModel injected which inherits
>   from any ViewModel that the grid is using, and contains two extra
>   properties: **record** and **recordIndex**
>
> The widget configuration may contain a cfg-bind config which uses the
>   ViewModel's data.

So you should use bind instead, like this:

```
xtype:'widgetcolumn',
dataIndex: 'canUpdateKey',
itemId:'updateKey',
width:120,
widget: {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Update key',
    bind: {
        hidden: '{!record.canUpdateKey}'
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26ig

Answer (score 0):

Inside your button widget, Try this:

```
listeners:{
                render:function(btn){
                    if(!btn.getWidgetRecord().data.canUpdateKey)
                    btn.hide();
                }
                }
```